# Login user by User object in django

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if there is a way to log in a test client without knowing the password. Something along the lines of:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_login_without_password(self):
        self.client.login(user_obj=User.objects.get(pk=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a clean way to login a user without a password: the only way suggested overloading the test client. At the end of the day, I wrote a decorator which creates an admin user and logs the user in.

```
from functools import wraps
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from faker import Faker


def create_admin_user_and_login(func):                                                                                                                                                                       
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        faker = Faker()
        username = faker.pronounceable_unique_id(length=30)
        password = faker.password()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            first_name=faker.word().title(),
            last_name=faker.word().title(),
            email=faker.email(),
            password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        self.client.login(username=username, password=password)
        return func(self)
    return wrapper
```

Where `faker.faker.Faker` is a class which generates some fake data.

Answer (score 0):

I think a user has to be authenticated before login.

I don't know whether User.objects.get() == authenticate(username, password), I think they are not.

Comment: I am aware of that, that's why I was looking for the way around Django's `authenticate` without using custom authentication back-end for testing.